# html_entity_decode not all entities converted back

Tags: php, laravel

i'm using PHP 7.2 on a ubuntu based os, and got this problem. searching stackoverflow only suggest these few things:

```
php artisan tinker
>>> html_entity_decode('&#174; &#153;', ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8');
=> "® &#153;"
>>> html_entity_decode('&#174; &#153;', ENT_QUOTES | ENT_HTML5, 'UTF-8');
=> "® &#153;"
```

[online demo](https://3v4l.org/3nWnE)

as you can see `&#153;` is not converted back to ™, but the `&#174;` is converted correctly.

any suggestion? how do i know which encoding to use for `&#153;`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In HTML coded character set, 127-159 is unused. There is no character assigned for 153. Maybe that is why it is not converting.

Check the [specification](https://www.w3.org/MarkUp/html-spec/html-spec_13.html)  for your coded character.

I checked a bit more. The code for ™ is 8482. Now it seems working perfectly.

check the [demo](https://3v4l.org/oaO2K)

Comment: hmmm, `&#153;` was converted by laravel from &trade; oh well, seems need to replace it with correct entity, thanks mate

Comment: your answer told me that i cannot convert `&#153;` with built in functions, which is want i wan't to do, so i'll wait if there is other options beside manually change it for a while, if no other options, i'll take your answer as best answer